# Summation of random variables converging to exponential

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

I want to know for what iid random variables $X_i$, the sum, $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i}{n^\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$ converges in distribution to an exponential distribution as $n \to \infty$. From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662570/summation-of-i-i-d-random-variables-of-what-distribution-has-exponential-distrib) I see that if the $X_i$ are $Gamma(\frac{1}{n}, \lambda)$ then the sum is exponential. The other example I am aware of is that the Geometric sum of random variables converges to exponential as the the parameter of the geometric distribution converges to 0. I want to know what other distributions are there where the sum converges to exponential. Note that I do not want the sum to be exactly exponential but just converges in distribution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If $\{X_i\}_{i \in \mathbb N}$ are i.i.d, then sequence $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ converges (a.s/in probability/in distribution) if and only if $X_i = 0$ almost surely and in that case $S_n$ converges to $0$.

Comment: My bad. Just edited the question

Comment: There are no such distributions I'm afraid. It can be shown, that if $\{X_i\}_{i \in \mathbb N_+}$ are i.i.d and for some sequences $(a_n)_n ,(b_n)_n$ with $a_n >0, b_n \in \mathbb R$ the sequence $a_n(X_1+...+X_n) + b_n$ converges in distribution (in our case $b_n = 0, a_n = \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$), then the limiting random variable must follow a stable distribution, but the exponential distribution isn't stable.

Comment: Oh I see. So is there any distribution other than the normal distribution for which this kind of result hold?

Comment: Or perhaps you are interested in characterizing a *sequence of distributions $(\mu_n)$* so that $$S_n \stackrel{d}{\to} \operatorname{Exp}(1),$$ where $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{n,i}$ and $X_{n,1},\ldots,X_{n,n} \sim \mu_n$ are independent. Then the link tells that one such choice is $\mu_n=\operatorname{Gamma}(\frac{1}{n},1)$.

Comment: @stochs Yes, those are exactly stable distributions. Gaussian is $2-$stable, for example Cauchy distribution is $1-$ stable, but there are many many more (but not so many more we can express in a "nice" analytical form). For example distributions with characteristic function of the form $e^{-|t|^\alpha}$ with $\alpha \in (0,2]$ are $\alpha-$stable. Case $\alpha = 2$ is Gaussian, case $\alpha = 1$ is Cauchy (as you might already know).

Comment: @DominikKutekDo you have any reference for CLT type of result where the target distribution is not Gaussian but one of these stable distributions?

Comment: English wikipedia page of "Stable distribution" has a paragraph about Generalised Central Limit Theorem. This is exactly something I had in mind. In particular, several references are discussed therein. One easy example is  the case od Cauchy distribution. Namely, if $X_i$ are Independent and standard Cauchy, then also $\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}$ is standard Cauchy, so in particular these averages converge in distribution to standard Cauchy.